# Using geographical graph data to guide Google Street View Static API

Tags: python, google-street-view, osmnx, google-street-view-static-api

I am trying to use geographical data - streets and intersections - derived from [osmnx](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx) together with the [Google Street View Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro) to get street view images that are

1. Taken from a intersection.
2. Looks directly down the road.

I have used osmnx (see code below) to get data that looks like this:

Nodes:

```
(NodeView((298466819, 20925446, 298466822, ...
```

And edges:

```
OutMultiEdgeView([(298466819, 8324095, 0), (298466819, 298466822, 0), (298466822, 8324094, 0), ...
```

So I can draw maps like this:

[image]

It can easily be converted to lat/long coordinates if that helps.

Using the Google API is quite simple with the [google_streetview](https://rrwen.github.io/google_streetview/) api:

```
import google_streetview.api

# Define parameters for street view api
params = [{
    'size': '640x640', # max 640x640 pixels
    'location': '55.6901769, 12.5595158',
    'heading': '0',
    'pitch': '0',
    'key': '--'
}]

# Create a results object
results = google_streetview.api.results(params)

results.preview()
```

What I need help to figure out, is, that given the nodes and edges, can I calculate the `heading` parameter for each node, such that I get at least one image from the node looking down the street?

---

Road map graph data:

```
import osmnx as ox
location_point = (55.6901, 12.5638)
G_nbro = ox.graph_from_point(location_point, distance=500, distance_type='network', network_type='drive')
```

---

Related:

[Getting the POV for Google StreetView API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068365/getting-the-pov-for-google-streetview-api)

[Is there a way to use the Google Street View API and only return "side view"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43946905/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-google-street-view-api-and-only-return-side-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

1. Get all connecting neighbours to a node:

```
nodes_dict = {node:nx.neighbors(G_nbro, node) for node in G_nbro.nodes}

for node in nodes_dict.keys():
    for nbr in nodes_dict[node]:
        print(node, nbr)
```

2. Get headings between each point. One point example here:

```
G_nbro[8322831][4555480822][0]['bearing']

311.045
```

Plug into Google API and it works beautifully.